# Sum Double from filtered fetch request?

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nsfetchrequest

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import CoreData

struct FilteredList: View {
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<FeedList>
    var value: FetchedResults<FeedList> {
        fetchRequest.wrappedValue
    }
    var total: Double = 0.0
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(value, id: \.self) {value in
            Text("Feed quantity is: \(value.feedquant.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value}) ")
        }
    }
    
    init(filter: String) {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<FeedList>(entity:
           FeedList.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FeedList.compdate, ascending: false)],
         predicate: NSPredicate(format: "compdate == %@", filter))
        
    }
    
}//: View
```

I have two attributes in my CoreData.  Compdate stored as a String of a date and feedquant stored as a double.  I am able to filter to get a fetch request of todays values through the init but I am unable to sum the attribute in a way that doesn't result in an error.  Like above any attempt to sum in the view results in

Type '()' cannot conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'. -or-
Type '()' does not conform to 'View"

So far no stackoverflow solution has worked for my case of summing an attribute in core data when having to filter by another attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have incorrectly written the code above. In your `ForEach`, you have a variable `value` which must be a collection (and I presume the result of your `FetchRequest`), but it is not defined anywhere. For the sake of this answer, I am going to assume that the first use of `value` is actually supposed to be `singer`.

@Fogmeister is correct as to the problem you are having with regard to the error messages. You have to have a `View` and your code did not supply one. However, you remain with another, deeper problem with trying to use `reduce()`

The problem you are having using `reduce()` is the way you have your `CoreData` model set up. You have an `Entity` entitled `FeedList` that has attributes of `date` and `feedquant`.

When you get in to your `ForEach`, `singer` is a collection, but `value` is an individual managed object that is simply a `String` and a `Double`, but you have to use `reduce` on a collection, not a `Double`.

You need to rethink your `CoreData` implementation. Personally, I would have two entities with a relationship. The first would be `Date` and the second would be `FeedQuant`. `FeedQuant` would have an attribute `value` which was a `Double`. I would then make a one to many relationship between `Date` and `Feedquant`. From `Date` I would call it `hasFeedquant`, and the inverse would be `hasDate`.

Your `FetchRequest` would remain the same except the entity would be a `Date` entity, but now you would get a relationship `hasFeedquant` that is a collection, and you could then use reduce on that.

Your code would then be:

```
struct FilteredList: View {
  var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<FeedList>
  var feedDate: FetchedResults<Date> {
    fetchRequest.wrappedValue
  }
  var total: Double = 0.0
        
  var body: some View {            
    ForEach(feedDate, id: \.self) {value in
      // value.hasFeedquant is a Set<Feedquant> and so is reducible
      Text("Feed quantity is: \(value.hasFeedquant.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value)") }
    }
  }
        
  init(filter: String) {
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Date>(
      entity: FeedList.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Date.compdate, ascending: false)],
      predicate: NSPredicate(format: "compdate == %@", filter)
    )        
  }
} //: View
```

Comment: I set it up this way and ran the code, and a new error comes up saying "Value of type 'Double' has no member 'reduce'

Comment: If you have a `Double`, then you set up a one to one relationship, not a one to many.  See [One-to-many relationships with Core Data, SwiftUI, and @FetchRequest](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/one-to-many-relationships-with-core-data-swiftui-and-fetchrequest). You need to have a `Collection` type to use `.reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have your view defined like...

```
var body: some View {            
  ForEach(value, id: \.self) { value in
    total = value.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.feedquant }
  }
}
```

You are not defining a `View` inside the `ForEach` so it doesn't know how to render a view.

`ForEach` is used to create multiple views with a given array. It isn't used to iterate an array like `forEach` would be in Swift.

Also... what is `value` that you are passing into this?

You would be able to display a total like...

```
var body: some View {            
  Text("\(someArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.feedquant })")
}
```

But I'm not entirely sure what your code is doing so I'm not certain what your data structure is.